# Does Guice intentionally execute noarg methods annotated with @Inject?

Tags: java, guice

I just noticed this after accidentally annotating a method with `@Inject` instead of `@Override`.  Does Guice intentionally allow this or is it something that should be considered a bug?

```java
public class GuiceExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bind(GuiceManagedResource.class);
            }
        });

        // The following is printed to the console:
        //
        // constructor
        // doSomethingUnexpected
        injector.getInstance(GuiceManagedResource.class);
    }

    static class GuiceManagedResource {
        @Inject
        GuiceManagedResource() {
            System.out.println("constructor");
        }

        @Inject
        void doSomethingUnexpected() {
            System.out.println("doSomethingUnexpected");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Injection is part of the initialization of the object. Any constructor, method or field annotated with `@Inject` will be processed. See the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/inject/Inject.html)

> Constructors are injected first, followed by fields, and then methods.

So, yes, if a method is found with the annotation `@Inject`, Guice will invoke it (following some rules).